# How to Subscribe to a ActiveMQ topic using its Ajax feature.

Tags: ajax, jsp, jakarta-ee, activemq-classic, long-polling

I am using ActiveMQ as my JMS provider and JSP to build up a real-time web application. The web application should subscribe to a topic produced in some other applications.

I have successfully deploy my we web application in Tomcat. Also, I have put all needed jar files in the lib directory. However, I still get an error, see the following error info from Google Chrome. Can someone tell me how to fix this problem.

[image]

[image]

My web.xml

```
     <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.activemq.brokerURL</param-name>
        <param-value>vm://localhost</param-value>
      </context-param>

     <servlet>
          <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/amq/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>MessageServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>MessageServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/message/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

My index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Rainbow for Nurse Station</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="amq/amq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var amq = org.activemq.Amq;
amq.init({ 
uri: 'amq', 
logging: true,
timeout: 20
});


var myHandler =  
{  
  rcvMessage: function(message)  
  {  
    document.writeln(message); 
  }  
};  


amq.addListener("test", "topic://RAINBOW_NURSECALL", myHandler.rcvMessage);

</script>

</head>
<body>

None.

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you simply missed to include the following 2 scripts *before* `amq.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your_path>/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your_path>/amq_jquery_adapter.js"></script>
```

because `org.activemq.Amq` requires `org.activemq.AmqAdapter` etc.